# Inheritance from a singleton class in java

Tags: java

I have a singleton class, call Class A, then I have another class, called Class B, and Class B extends from class A. What I want is that, after instance of class A is created, when the instance of class B is created after that, it will have the same information as class A have. Is it possible in Java ?

Thank you very much.

P/S: This is how I created a singleton class

```
public static A getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new A();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Depends, how are you making sure it's a singleton?

Comment: You probably just need to make a Constructor for B that takes the instance of `A` as a parameter, and then copy itself into B.

Comment: The *design* path you are taking will give you *sleepless nights*. beware my friend.. There are workarounds to do this, but definitely not advisable. Singleton almost always is used in a *has-a* relationship (if at all)

Comment: It doesn't look like singleton since singletons have private constructor which prevents it from being extended (unless `B` is inner class of `A`)

Comment: @Pshemo wait, you can't extend from a class with a private constructor? I didn't know that. Cool.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You need to be able to invoke `super()` in extending class constructor, but if this `super` is private then it is impossible to invoke it, which makes our `extend` pointless.

Comment: If you have a singleton `A` and `B extends A` and you somehow allow this through a `protected` constructor in `A` then you effectively have two instances of `A`. That is not the _singleton_ pattern at all.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Technically, you can extend from a class with a private constructor in the same compilation unit (meaning that nested or private classes can extend).

Comment: @chrylis - Or by adding another constructor which isn't private :P

Comment: @EpicPandaForce if you want to prevent class from being extend, define it as `final`

Comment: @user902383 Aye, I knew about that :) although nowadays if I need a singleton, I just use the `enum singleton pattern` like so http://stackoverflow.com/a/27040452/2413303

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, i'm using enum for single tons as well, at least since i read effective java

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from a singleton class A by making A's constructor `protected` instead of `private`.

But if you're inheriting from singletons, you should probably take another look at your design.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed this is a bad design, but it is just curious thought of me :)